# Why is a proper action defined as the map $G\times M\rightarrow M\times M$ by $(g,m)\mapsto (gm, m)$ being proper rather than closed?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, lie-groups

If one is saying "proper action", it would indeed be surprising to require the map to be closed.

However, in the application of this property that I know, what matters is getting a Hausdorff orbit space, which comes from $\{(gm,m)\,|\,g\in G, m\in M\}$ being a closed subset of $M\times M$.

If $M$ is sequential, so is the product $M\times M$ and any proper map into it will be closed. In this case "proper" seems to be stronger than needed.

Conversely, if $M$ is not sequential, $\{(gm,m)\,|\,g\in G, m\in M\}$ may not be closed even if the map $(g,m)\mapsto (gm,m)$ is proper, so the orbit space will not be Hausdorff.

Comment: Because the useful condition is properness and not closed, of course. Properness allows you to "bound" the preimage of small (that is, compact) things.

Comment: For example... ?

Comment: Well, a trivial example is that the stabilizer of a point under a proper action is compact, but if the action is only "closed" as you propose then not so much.